# Xcode Outlet generation does not generate @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, synthesize

I am having an issue with Drag and Drop Outlet generation, for some reason Xcode stopped generating @synthesize to the .m file, the @property is added correctly to the .h file.

Also I find it odd that an @interface block is added to the .m file even so the .h file with the @interface exists.

```
@interface BlahController {

}

@implementation BlahController : UIViewController {
    //Code
}
```

Comment: There are a million questions about this floating around, but basically 1) you don't need @synthesize at all anymore and 2) that is your class extension - an interface only visible to your .m Put private things here. So this is a feature, not a bug, literally.

Comment: But XCode does not recognise the variable without the @synthezise statement, so I can't run the code like that. Are both those features new for ios6?

Comment: nope it will compile down just fine. If your version of xCode is new enough to not generate `@synthesize` then it is new enough to pick up variables without it. Try cleaning the project, deleting the derived data etc... it should be fine.

Comment: @dngfng stop going through instance variable then, use the property ;) No but actually they synthesize to _propertyName so if you need to access ivar use that.

Comment: Hold up - all that I am doing is dragging and dropping to generate and outlet with @property. The Project is new and clean, no old bagage... and yet xcode is complaining and not compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Advanced thank you to Carl Veazey, who pretty much wrote up this answer in the comments:

1. The interface is for private variables.
2. The "missing" @property have to be accessed by _variableName.

Many Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

> I am having an issue with Drag and Drop Outlet generation, for some
>   reason Xcode stopped generating @synthesize to the .m file, the
>   @property is added correctly to the .h file.

The newest version of the compiler doesn't require `@synthesize` directives anymore. Just declaring a property using the `@property` directive is enough to cause the accessor(s) to be synthesized unless you use either the `@dynamic` directive or provide your own accessor(s) for the property.